# Postgresql delete action for copy command

Tags: postgresql

I have this code

```
create or replace function foo(text)returns int as $$ begin
copy (select * from (delete from bar a where a.id not in(select b.id from bar b where a.id=b.id limit 32 offset 0) returning *) as g) to '/home/foo/.bar.data';
return 1;
end $$ language plpgsql cost 50;
```

but it cannot create the function and gives the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 4: copy(select * from(delete from bar a ...
                                  ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 29
```

The delete command `(delete from bar ...)` is prepared and run without any problem when I call it alone.
I also tried this(without select), same error.

```
copy (delete from bar a where a.id not in(select b.id from bar b where a.id=b.id limit 32 offset 0) returning *) to '/home/foo/.bar.data';
```

All I want is delete from the table and copy to a file.
Also how may I have void method in pgsql?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:
[Using return value from DELETE for UPDATE in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997246/using-return-value-from-delete-for-update-in-postgres)

The accepted answer there may point you in the right direction.  It appears there is some inherent PostgreSQL limitation surrounding the use of `DELETE` in a subquery, which may extend to `COPY`. The linked question specifically discusses the complications of using `DELETE` results in an `UPDATE`, but the workaround provided may work for your use case as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use COPY like that, as the syntax doesn't support using a subquery. And the [`file_fdw`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) is read-only insofar as I'm aware, so that would would work either.

What might work instead, is something like:

```
create temporary table ... as
delete from ... returning *;
```

... and then `copy` the temporary table to a file.